# How to check the order of appearance on django test

Tags: python, django, testunit

I use this sentences to check the letters `line1` and `line2` appears.

self.assertContains(response,"line1");
self.assertContains(response,"line2");

However I want to check the order of appearance.

I checked in this page, but can't figure out which I should use.

`https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertContains`

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want to assert that line 1 appears in the response before line2?

There isn't (probably; I haven't checked but would be quite surprised) a specific command that would assert that.

Instead, use `find()` to get the indices of where in the response `line1` and `line2` are found, then compare them.

EDIT: But be aware that if the content isn't found, `find` will return `-1`. A solution could be to first just use your `assertContains` to check that `line1` and `line2` are present, and after that use `find()` to verify that one comes before the other.

Comment: Take into account that `find` returns -1 when substring is not found. It can lead to false results. For example when `line1` is not found

Answer (score 1):

You can also try doing that with regex.

```
# This will match the line where "line1" appears first, then anything in between and then "line2".
regex_expression = r"line1.*line2"

self.assertRegex(response, regex)
```

If you don't like it then use .index() method.

```
self.assertContains(response,"line1")
self.assertContains(response,"line2")

line1_index = response.index("line1")
line2_index = response.index("line2")

self.assertTrue(line1_index < line2_index)
```